# How to replace a string in a file with other file.

Tags: bash, command-line

I am trying to replace a string in a file1 with a file2

file1.txt

```
 This is first line in file.
```

file2.txt

```
 Hello world
```

I am trying to replace "This" word with "Hello World"

file1.txt

```
Hello world is first line in file.
```

I tried with sed

```
sed -i 's/This/`cat file2.txt`\g' file1.txt

cat file2.txt is first line in file.
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-to-use-variables-in-sed-command)

Comment: @sjsam its working with double quotes. Thanks a lot ...

Comment: Single quotes mean that the command substitution isn't done; use double quotes, and use `/` instead of ``\`` to end the `s///` command.  Then you'd be in with a chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-to-use-variables-in-sed-command) which says :

> The shell is responsible for expanding variables. If you use single
>   quotes for strings, the contents will be treated literally

Your solution is to use double quotes like below:

```
var=$(< file2.txt)
sed -i "s/This/$var/" file1.txt
```

Comment: @micha-wiedenmann : Thanks for the tip which said `$(cat file) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< file)`.. Cool indeed..